# Why does anybody ever use int data type?

Tags: c++, types, int, long-integer, short

In C++ (which i am learning and am still very very new to), I have noticed that almost everybody uses the `int` data type. But why? I know that `short`, `long`, and `long long` have definite sizes pretty much, but `int` seems like it might be `short` or `long` depending on the system. So, why don't people be more specific about the types? If they put a number into an `int` that is too big for a `short`, then on certain systems it will be really bad. If the number you're putting into an `int` is small enough to fit into a `short`, then on systems where it defaults to `long` memory space is wasted. So why does everybody use `int`?

Comment: None of the classic integral types in C++ has a definite size. Not one. Also, what would the alternative to using `int` be? Using `short` or `long`? You could then express the exact same doubts that you have now.

Comment: Great example where the "`long` has size X" has bit people: `long` is 64 bit on many 64 bit systems, but 32 bits on 64 bit Windows and most 32 bit systems. A lot of important code is broken (or was, until every cast in the whole project was carefully checked and changed) on a popular platform, because it was used for fiddling with pointers' arithmetic values, instead of `[u]intptr_t` or at least a typedef that can be made portable after the fact.

Comment: I think programmers use `int` for some basic reasons: 1) It's short `int` is only 3 letters compared to others and 2) Its [the basic integer type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the standard (C++11, §3.9.1/2),

> Plain `int`s have the natural size suggested by the
>   architecture of the execution environment; the other signed integer types are provided to meet special
>   needs.

So `int` is the type you should use unless you have a good reason to use any other type, because `int` is supposed to map to the type that the architecture is optimized to use most of the time.

Comment: It might be supposed to map to that *most of the time*, but in practice, it does not: on today's desktop computers, `int`s are 32 bits, yet the platform can handle 64-bit numbers.

Answer (score 5):

You're correct in that `int` has a variable size. But short, long, and long long also have variable sizes. So they aren't a better option.

I'm not going to speculate on why people use `int` because that would just be my opinion.

If you need an actually true sized integer though, you should use `int32_t` or `uint32_t` or `int64_t`. These types have required sizes.

Comment: ok. Thanks! The book im using (C++ Primer) was a bit confusing. It seemed to say that `short` and `long` had definite sizes.

Comment: @Markasoftware: The only guarantee you get is that each type is at least as large as the previous one: char <= short <= int <= long.

Comment: Well, there's also the guarantee that short is _at least_ 16 bits and long is _at least_ 32 bits.